# How does the objective argument work in python's xgboost?

Tags: python, machine-learning, xgboost

[Gradient boosted trees can take a custom objective function](https://xgboost.readthedocs.io/en/latest/model.html). This is great, because for my particular task I have a very specific **loss function** where I can calculate the first and second order derivatives with respect to the predictions.

To be clear, in general the objective function of a machine learning task is usually defined as obj = loss + complexity.

However, I want to leave the standard complexity penalty, given by `Omega(f) = gamma*T + (1/2)*lambda * \sum_{j=1}^T(w^2_j)`, unchanged. Here, `T,gamma,lambda,w` are the number of leaves in a tree, minimum loss reduction required to make a further partition on a leaf node of the tree, L2 regularization term on weights and vector of weights per leaf respectively.

My question is, using the [standard python implementation of xgboost](http://xgboost.readthedocs.io/en/latest/parameter.html), can I define **just the loss function** as input to the `objective` argument and let the xgboost library take care of the complexity term? This would be great, because I do not want to change the complexity term or calculate its derivatives.

My guess is that, unfortunately we must also define the complexity term since, by definition, the objective function is a linear combination of both the loss and the complexity.

NOTE: If we look at the notes for XGBClassifier

```
from xgboost import XGBClassifier
help(XGBClassifier)
...
|  objective : string or callable
|      Specify the learning task and the corresponding learning objective or
|      a custom objective function to be used (see note below).
...
...
|  Note
|  ----
|  A custom objective function can be provided for the ``objective``
|  parameter. In this case, it should have the signature
|  ``objective(y_true, y_pred) -> grad, hess``:
|  
|  y_true: array_like of shape [n_samples]
|      The target values
|  y_pred: array_like of shape [n_samples]
|      The predicted values
|  
|  grad: array_like of shape [n_samples]
|      The value of the gradient for each sample point.
|  hess: array_like of shape [n_samples]
|      The value of the second derivative for each sample point
```

we see that the only inputs to a custom `objective` function should be `y_pred` and `y_true`. So I don't understand, if we do need to define the complexity term, how the complexity parameters (`T,gamma,lambda,w`) would be defined in a custom objective function.

Comment: Are you sure you need to handle the complexity term at all? The docs do not mention it anywhere and the second term in your comlexity definition is in fact an L2 regularisation, which is handled by XGBoost internally as long as you set the corresponding input parameter (`reg_lambda` in this case, but there is also a way to add L1 term, if you want to)

Comment: I think that this is clumsy terminology in xgboost. When you set a custom "objective" function, you are setting a custom loss function, and xgboost is then adding its standard regularisation to your loss function. If this were not the case, if you set up a loss function with no regularisation, your training procedure should not be in any way sensitive to parameters such as reg_lambda. A quick examination of an xgboost notebook I have using a custom loss function, shows that raising reg_lambda drastically affects the train time, so it must be doing something.